# Spark : How to alter oracle session (nls_date_format) from spark?

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that contains Timestamp column (2021-01-19 13:00:30).
When i send this dataframe to an existing table in Oracle (19c) using Spark (2) Scala jdbc, it insert 2021-01-19 13:00:30.**000000** even if the column in Oracle is TIMESTAMP(0)

Exemple :
`df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, tableName, connectionProperties)`

I tried to alter session from Spark before sending data, by creating connection than execute the code :

```
connection.setAutoCommit(true)
val statement: Statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.executeQuery("alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS")
```

But it doesn't really alter the session (I have no error).

Should I specify in `df.write ...` the pattern of my Timestamp ? Otherwise, am I altering correctly the session from Spark ?

Comment: This feels like an XY-problem. Why don't you fix the `INSERT` statement rather than trying to alter the session? Also, if it is a `TIMESTAMP` data type then using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is going to have zero effect; you want `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`.

Comment: Values stored in a `timestamp` (or `date`) column never have a human-readable format.  They're stored in a single packed binary format.  If the session that reads the data queries a `timestamp` without doing an explicit `to_char` and the reader wants a string representation, the reader's `nls_timestamp_format` would be used to do the conversion.  If the reader's `nls_timestamp_format` includes fractional seconds, the resulting string will have fractional seconds even if they are always 0.  That would happen regardless of what the inserting session's NLS settings.